# Prevent div from moving down when other div is resized

Tags: html, css, scroll, resize

I have three divs in my page arranged side by side. The first two are resizable. When I resize any of the two, the third div automatically goes down. I want to prevent this and instead want a horizontal scrollbar to appear for the third div since it has very less space to display. I don't want to limit the max-width of first two divs.
I tried some methods which were provided in Stack overflow (putting all 3 divs into a parent div/wrap and define css width etc.,)
A sample of what my page looks like is here - [Codepen](https://codepen.io/sohailakther/pen/KKNrJgB)

HTML:

```
<div class="c1">
    <p> column 1 </p>
</div>
<div class="c2">
    <p> column 2 </p>
</div>
<div class="c3">
    <p> column 3 </p>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.c1 {
    resize: horizontal;
    overflow: auto;
    width: 50%;
    float: left;
}
.c2 {
    resize: horizontal;
    overflow: auto;
    width: 30%;
    float: left;
}
.c3 {
    resize: horizontal;
    float: left;
    width: 10%;
}
```

Thanks.

p.s: This is my first question on Stack overflow, please excuse if there's any mistake (Suggest me how I can improve if possible).

Answer (score 0):

I solved this by putting my divs into a parent div 'container' and applying

```
.container {
    display: flex;
}
```

I've updated the codepen in question. Please correct if I'm wrong.